# PostgreSQL to MySQL MySQL Workbench migration error

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, database-migration

I am trying to migrate a PostgreSQL database to MySQL using MySQL Workbench. I have been able to connect to both databases but when I get to the Reverse Engineer Source step I get the error below.

The system is using PostgreSQL 8.1.23. Old I know which is why we a are migrating the system to the latest version of MySQL.

This post has a similar issue but not exactly the same [PostgreSQL to MySQL data migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729820/postgresql-to-mysql-data-migration)

I am guessing it is an issue with a sequence but not sure how to track it down.

Thanks!

`Starting...
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting...
Connecting to postgresql@DRIVER=PostgreSQL ANSI(x64);SERVER=162.242.171.94;PORT=5432...
Opening ODBC connection to DRIVER=PostgreSQL ANSI(x64);SERVER=123.456.123.456;PORT=5432;DATABASE=xxxxxxx;UID=xxxx;UseDeclareFetch=1;...
Connected
Connect to source DBMS done
Reverse engineer selected schemas....
Reverse engineering public from xxxxxxx
- Reverse engineering catalog information
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_postgresql_re_grt.py", line 352, in reverseEngineer
    return PostgresqlReverseEngineering.reverseEngineer(connection, catalog_name, schemata_list, context)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_generic_re_grt.py", line 237, in reverseEngineer
    catalog = cls.reverseEngineerCatalog(connection, catalog_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_generic_re_grt.py", line 397, in reverseEngineerCatalog
    cls.reverseEngineerSequences(connection, schema)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_postgresql_re_grt.py", line 76, in reverseEngineerSequences
    min_value, max_value, start_value, increment_by, last_value, is_cycled, ncache = cls.execute_query(connection, seq_details_query % (schema.name, seq_name)).fetchone()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_generic_re_grt.py", line 76, in execute_query
    return cls.get_connection(connection_object).cursor().execute(query, *args, **kwargs)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42703', '[42703] ERROR: column "start_value" does not exist;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 192, in thread_work
    self.func()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\migration_schema_selection.py", line 175, in task_reveng
    self.main.plan.migrationSource.reverseEngineer()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\migration.py", line 369, in reverseEngineer
    self.state.sourceCatalog = self._rev_eng_module.reverseEngineer(self.connection, self.selectedCatalogName, self.selectedSchemataNames, self.state.applicationData)
SystemError: ProgrammingError("('42703', '[42703] ERROR: column "start_value" does not exist;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.reverseEngineer
ERROR: Reverse engineer selected schemas: ProgrammingError("('42703', '[42703] ERROR: column "start_value" does not exist;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.reverseEngineer
Failed

Comment: In MySQL Workbench db_postgresql_migration_grt.py has start_value in the SQL statement, line #70. Since there is no start_value column I assume this is the source of the issue. Any suggestions on how this should be replaced?

Comment: I am having the same problem too and I wonder if our postgres version is higher than the workbench supports since where I read the workbench tutorial is actually from 2012 and lots of changed during these years.

Comment: Have you found out a better way to do the migration?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in this location WORKBENCH_INSTALLATION_PATH/modules/db_postgresql_re_grt.py

Replace:

```
    seq_details_query = """SELECT min_value, max_value, start_value, 
increment_by, last_value, is_cycled, cache_value
FROM "%s"."%s" """
```

for:

```
    seq_details_query = """SELECT min_value, max_value, start_value, 
increment_by, last_value, cycle as is_cycled, cache_size as cache_value
FROM pg_catalog.pg_sequences
WHERE schemaname = '%s' AND sequencename = '%s' """
```

Then restart MySQL Workbench and retry migrating, the issue will be solved