# Error migrating from PostgreSQL to MySQL [42703]

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, mysql-workbench

I have a database in Postgres that I would like to migrate to MySQL, but whenever I get to the reverse engineering stage of the MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard I get an error. The error is:

```
    ERROR: Reverse engineer selected schemas: ProgrammingError("('42703', '[42703] ERROR: column "min_value" does not exist;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.reverseEngineer
Failed
```

The full error log is:

```
    File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_generic_re_grt.py", line 237, in reverseEngineer
    catalog = cls.reverseEngineerCatalog(connection, catalog_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_generic_re_grt.py", line 397, in reverseEngineerCatalog
    cls.reverseEngineerSequences(connection, schema)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_postgresql_re_grt.py", line 76, in reverseEngineerSequences
    min_value, max_value, start_value, increment_by, last_value, is_cycled, ncache = cls.execute_query(connection, seq_details_query % (schema.name, seq_name)).fetchone()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_generic_re_grt.py", line 76, in execute_query
    return cls.get_connection(connection_object).cursor().execute(query, *args, **kwargs)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42703', '[42703] ERROR: column "min_value" does not exist;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 192, in thread_work
    self.func()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\migration_schema_selection.py", line 175, in task_reveng
    self.main.plan.migrationSource.reverseEngineer()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\migration.py", line 369, in reverseEngineer
    self.state.sourceCatalog = self._rev_eng_module.reverseEngineer(self.connection, self.selectedCatalogName, self.selectedSchemataNames, self.state.applicationData)
SystemError: ProgrammingError("('42703', '[42703] ERROR: column "min_value" does not exist;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.reverseEngineer
ERROR: Reverse engineer selected schemas: ProgrammingError("('42703', '[42703] ERROR: column "min_value" does not exist;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.reverseEngineer
Failed
```

I tried modifying the Python script as described in the top comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729820/postgresql-to-mysql-data-migration), but that did not stop the error. Does anyone know how I could resolve this?

Comment: Do you have a Postgre version number between `9.0` and `9.1`? If so, the instructions in [**this bug report**](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68997) may help you.

Comment: I saw that, but I'm running `10.1.3`. Thanks though.

Comment: In PostgreSQL 10 `min_value` was moved from sequences relations to `pg_sequence` catalog table as `seqmin`. Not really sure how to solve this for Workbench tho.

Comment: Good tip @ŁukaszKamiński! I had the choice between PostgreSQL versions so stepping back to 9.6 helped me out here.

Answer (score 16):

Fix File `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_postgresql_re_grt.py"` lines ~70 change to

```
seq_details_query = """SELECT min_value, max_value, start_value, 
increment_by, last_value, cycle as is_cycled, cache_size as cache_value
FROM pg_catalog.pg_sequences
WHERE schemaname = '%s' AND sequencename = '%s' """
```

Comment: Worked for me on Mac. Same file, located `/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/db_postgresql_re_grt.py`

Comment: worked for me too on Unbuntu 16, with Mysql wokBench 6.3.  (and destination to mysql 5.7 ). Thanks a lot.  Location file /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_postgresql_re_grt.py

Comment: How does one come up with solutions like this? You are a genius.

Comment: This seems to still occur in Workbench 8.0.20 with PostgreSQL 13.1.1 (Windows) and this fix worked.

Comment: if this doesn't seem to work for you right away, make sure you restart Workbench after you change the .py file. I could've saved myself a few headslams if I didn't forget to do that. once I did, worked like a charm.

Comment: PG 15,  Workbench 8.0 - still works, thank you!
Also got help for other fields from here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93594
```cycle as is_cycled, cache_size as cache_value```

Answer (score 0):

I have PostgreSQL 10.5

Replaced in db_postgresql_re_grt.py:80

```
min_value, max_value, start_value, increment_by, last_value, is_cycled, ncache = cls.execute_query(connection, seq_details_query % (schema.name, seq_name)).fetchone()
```

with:

```
last_value, log_cnt, is_called = cls.execute_query(connection, """SELECT last_value, log_cnt, is_called FROM "%s"."%s" """ % (schema.name, seq_name)).fetchone()
seqrelid, seqtypid, seqstart, seqincrement, seqmax, seqmin, seqcache, seqcycle = cls.execute_query(connection, "select seqrelid, seqtypid, seqstart, seqincrement, seqmax, seqmin, seqcache, seqcycle from pg_sequence where seqrelid = '%s'::regclass" % seq_name).fetchone()
min_value = seqmin
max_value = seqmax
start_value = seqstart
increment_by = seqincrement
is_cycled = seqcycle
ncache = seqcache
```